# How can I select all parents hierarchically?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table like this:

```
// tags
+----+--------------+-----------+---------+
| id |   tag_name   | parent_id | related |
+----+--------------+-----------+---------+
| 1  | programming  | NULL      | 1       |
| 2  | medical      | NULL      | 2       |
| 3  | juridical    | NULL      | 3       |
| 4  | HTML         | 1         | 1       |
| 5  | PHP          | 1         | 1       |
| 6  | function     | 5         | 1       |
| 7  | ampoule      | 2         | 2       |
| 8  | needle       | 7         | 2       |
| 9  | CSS          | 1         | 1       |
| 10 | echo         | 5         | 1       |
| 11 | padding      | 9         | 1       |
+----+--------------+-----------+---------+
```

Also I have this value: `function`. Now I want to select all its parents. So this is expected result:

```
+----+--------------+-----------+---------+
| id |   tag_name   | parent_id | related |
+----+--------------+-----------+---------+
| 1  | programming  | NULL      | 1       |
| 5  | PHP          | 1         | 1       |
+----+--------------+-----------+---------+
```

How can I do that?

---

**Note:** `related` column has nothing to do with this question. It've added it because sometimes I need to select all related tags *(both parents and children)*.

Comment: MySQL is not designed to store hierarchical data.  The only real way to do this is using a stored procedure with a `while` loop.  However, you can store the data a bit differently to do what you want.  Here is a good blog post on ways to do this:  http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/.

Answer (score -1):

It might be better to get one level at a time from your code to get his data. But if you know how many levels you have in your hierarchies you can prepare code for this.

If you have a maximum of 4 hierarchies including the last level this code would work. Then you can add more unions for more levels or remove the last union if you dont have as many levels.

I have set the name 'tableName' on your table here and just wrote it together quickly but this should work. Let me know if it does not work and i will try to find a mysql server to run against.

```
SELECT t1.* 
FROM tableName t1 
JOIN tableName t2 ON t1.id = t2.parent_id 
WHERE t2.tag_name = 'function'
UNION ALL
SELECT t1.* 
FROM tableName t1 
JOIN tableName t2 ON t1.id = t2.parent_id 
JOIN tableName t3 ON t2.id = t3.parent_id 
WHERE t3.tag_name = 'function'
UNION ALL
SELECT t1.* 
FROM tableName t1 
JOIN tableName t2 ON t1.id = t2.parent_id 
JOIN tableName t3 ON t2.id = t3.parent_id 
JOIN tableName t4 ON t3.id = t4.parent_id 
WHERE t4.tag_name = 'function'
ORDER BY ID
```

(Changing 'function' to a variable is of course a good idea)